# Moving Rows Up and Down in DataTables using buttons in toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ns1rr084/) example of table I'm using. I'm getting ID of selected row using `window.id`.

So I need to code a function so that when the user wants to move row 51 to row 3. (user click on row 51 and then clicking on button UP it moves row by one row up until row 51 is on position 3). I also need to all rows to dynamically renumber when clicking on button UP or DOWN button.

Comment: see this once http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html and also http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: thanks...but i see this is only client side processing...i need server side processing

Comment: What are you using on your server side? It's clear that you must update your datasource on the server via a script, then reload the updated datasource. This has not really much to do with javascript. So what is it (php/mysql or else)?

Comment: on server u need to do by teiryu ex:ASC,DESC

Comment: i im using server side because i have large data...around 800records...and it will grow ever large in time..so i need speed f loading table...

Comment: is there any drag up and drag down jquery api that i can add to onclick event? here is example: http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rowGrouping.html   so i need to when i click in toolbar UP button that function up click call drag and drop up isths possibl in jquery?